# Not Able to call API on RPC end points

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I have started Sync of ETH node to my VPS. I want to call RPC Call to get balance details of addresses. What i have done is as below:
1) Install geth started geth service
2) geth --fast --rpc

After few hours i have stopped geth sync and add some peers using admin.addPeers() method

Again start geth sync using below command on specific port

geth --syncmode light console --rpc --rpcport 3000

after this i have fired admin.peers it shows empty Array so i have add some peers and then check using admin.peers below is the image of admin.peers

[image]

Now i am still not able to call RPC Call on my IP 5.101.139.166:3000
I am getting error

Error: Couldn't connect to server
Here are some additional things that may help.

Documentation  Contact Support
Loading...
Cancel Request
Unknown Response Code0.000 milliseconds
Read
Current Status of Node sync is as below
[image]

Error while calling RPC Call
[image]

Comment: from where and how  are you calling Geth exposed RPC server ?

Comment: I am calling RPC all to server by specified port 3000

Comment: I mean from browser or Node.js or anything else?

Comment: Are you using curl or web3 to consume RPC API’s?

Comment: I am calling from postman or restclient. as it is not responding in postman it will not reflact in other restclient also

Comment: Can you post a snapshot? Btw use —rpccorsdomain="*"  while running Geth

Comment: I have just check by adding --rpccorsdomain="*" but i am getting same error. What i have done is like 1) Stop sync 2) restart by adding clause 3) check admin.peers shows empty so add two peers 
4) check eth.syncing it returns false, Still API call using RPC is giving same error Could not connect to server

Comment: change port to 5.101.139.166:3000 instead of 5.101.139.166:8545 because you are running RPC server at port 3000 . look --rpcport 3000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start geth by this command will solve the problem. Using below command it allows all other IP to access it.

geth --syncmode light console --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use this geth option 
`--rpccorsdomain "*"` 
(or 
`--rpccorsdomain "5.101.139.166"`)?

To accept cross origin requests, this rpccorsdomain option should be set when you launch geth from console.

Comment: Okay, Let me try this

Comment: This is not working, I have checked, it shows same error.

Comment: I have added answer that fixed my problem. But still i am getting some minor issues like "no suitable peers available"

Answer (score 0):

As you have started RPC server at port 3000, when running Geth with option **--rpcport=3000**.
So while consuming RPC API's use port 3000, instead of default port 8545.
That will solve your problem.

Comment: This is not a actual problem.

Comment: then what is the problem? As far as i can see in postman , you are sending JSON-RPC request to port 8545